# Excel macro to highlight all cells that match value in current cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a macro that will automatically highlight any cells in the current worksheet if the value of those cells is the same as the currently-selected cell. So if cell B3 is currently selected, and it contains the value 3, then all other cells with a value of 3 will be highlighted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Reafidy provided a good macro and this will do the same with conditional formatting

```
Sub HighLightCells()
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:=ActiveCell
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End Sub
```

Put this in the sheet selection change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 call HighLightCells
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing the change event part.

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional formatting.

If you really need a macro then:

```
Sub HighlightCells()
Dim rCell As Range

If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Set rCell = ActiveCell

Do
    Set rCell = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Find(ActiveCell.Value, rCell)

    If rCell.Address <> ActiveCell.Address Then
        rCell.Interior.Color = 65535
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```